# Symfony 4.4 service autowired in controller's constructor doesn't get call from service definition (setContainer)

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Foreword: please disregard injecting the whole container and other unclean things, I just wanted to show not-working example, this is before refactor.

I have a service defined in YAML:

```
app.service.my_service:
    class: App\Services\MyService
    public: true
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
```

part of my service:

```
class MyService implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    /** @var ContainerInterface */
    private $container;

    /** @var EntityManagerInterface */
    private $em;

    public function setContainer(?ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->em = $container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    }
```

Then I have a controller, which have that service autowired in constructor, and not instantiaded from container:

```
class MyController
{
    /**
     * @var MyService
     */
    private $my_service;

    function __construct(MyService $my_service) {
        $this->my_service = $my_service;
    }
```

While it actually autowires service itself, **it completely ignores the `setContainer` call, so I end up with empty container**.
I wanted to avoid calling `$this->get('app.service.my_service')` everywhere and I can't simply call it once in controller's contructor, or call `setContainer` in the constructor on autowired service, because at that time container is empty.
Any chances I can do it in a clean way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already know injecting the container is a bad idea then I guess I'll spare you the lecture.  I have not encountered this particular issue but you can try using the little known '@required' container directive and see if it helps.

```
/** @required */
public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
{
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->em = $container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager);
}
```

This is more of a guess than an answer but it is easy to try.

Update: It worked. Cool.

I just wanted to add that, in most cases, dependencies should be injected into the constructor.  This avoids having partially initialized services.  On the other hand, as long as you are generating your services via the container then it is not really a problem.

I find it to be very useful in traits.  For example:

```
trait RouterTrait
{
    private RouterInterface $router;

    /** @required */
    public function setRouter(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = isset($this->router) ? $this->router: $router;
    }
    // These are just copied from AbstractController
    protected function generateUrl(
        return $this->router->generate(...
    protected function redirectToRoute(
#
class SomeService
    use RouterTrait;
    public function someMethod()
        $this->generateUrl('''
```

So if a service needs to do some routing then they just need to use the router trait and the router is automatically injected.  Saves adding boilerplate code to the service's constructor.  I do put a guard around setRouter so it can only be effectively called once which eliminates another concern about using setters for dependencies.

Update #2:
The problem with the original code is that the MyService was defined with a service is of app.service.my_service and not the class name.  Autowire actually generated a second MyService and injected it since autowire looks for service ids that match the class name. Changing the service definition to:

```
App\Services\MyService:
    public: true
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
```

Would have also worked.  Or explicitly injecting app.service.my_service into the controller.

Comment: Seems like your guess was better than my 30 minutes of trying and reading docs, because I seem to have missed that one. Thank you!
EDIT: I would upvote, but I don't have enough rep., sorry.

Comment: BTW `@required` works only if autowiring is enabled. Your solution with an explicit `setContainer` call should work too. Looks like your service is overridden somewhere else. Like this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#importing-many-services-at-once-with-resource - if you define your service before this directive, it will be overridden and `setContainer` will not be called. With `@required` you defeat a symptom, not a disease

Comment: @DmitrySolovov You are of course absolutely correct in that autowire is needed for required to work.  The actual problem is pretty simple.  They are using an older style service id ('app.service.my_service') to define their service.  Autowire is actually defining and injecting a second MyService service.  Had they simply used the class name as the service id then all would be well.  I just wanted to see if the annotation would work.

Comment: No, autowire will not define any services. It will only inject dependencies to existing services.
The reason of the OP's problem is this directive https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#importing-many-services-at-once-with-resource. It will automatically create services for every class in listed folders by their class names. He should exclude his service (or the entire folder) from this autoimport. Or, as you said, name the service by its class name (better solution).

Comment: Hmmm.  Not sure if we are saying the same thing or not.  With the original code we would end up with two MyService services.  One with an id of app.service.my_service and one with an id of MyService::class.  You can verify this using the debug:container command.  Had he simply excluded the MyService class from autowire then the attempt to inject MyService into the controller would have failed since there would be no service with an id of MyService::class.