# Is a was to make translator in Symfony 4/5 as public service

Tags: symfony

I know I can inject Translator via contruct:

```
__construct(TranslatorInterface $translator) {

}
```

but I don't want in each of my controllers to add another dependency in __construct. I have controllers that extend Symfony AbstractController (`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController`) and there is a container which have some of the dependencies but translator is not one of them. I can use twig in controllers without injecting it manually but not translator. It does not make sense, translator is one of the basic services like twig but it's not available in container. Is there any option that I can make translator available in this AbstractController container so I can use `$this->container->get('translator')` in my controllers?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66061859/symfony3-4-how-to-specify-a-service-with-an-argument/66102874#66102874) shows how to add subscribed services to your controller.  As an alternative, you can make a TranslatorTrait similar to [this one](https://github.com/cerad/zayso4/blob/master/src/Core/LoggerTrait.php).  The ATrequired annotation causes the setter to be called automatically.  I should point out that the fact that the translator is not available via the default AbstractController sort of implies that you should not be using it in your action methods.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62794134/symfony-4-4-service-autowired-in-controllers-constructor-doesnt-get-call-from/62794378#62794378) is another example of how to use a trait with automatic injection.

Comment: @Cerad great thanks, subscribed events that the thing I was looking for. In my controller action methods I just simply want to translate flash messages, I don't think it is something that I shouldn't do.

Comment: But are you not using Twig to ultimately display these flash messages?  Seems like that would be where the translation would occur.  In any event, good luck.